# shutting down Mongo server from C# Driver API

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to shutdown the MongoDB server from my C# application when application exits.

I am using `RunAdminCommand` of `MongoServer` object to do this. Below is the code snippet.

```
MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create( @"mongodb://localhost:27019" );
server.RunAdminCommand ( @"shutdown" ) ;
```

The execution freezes at the second line and never returns back, though I see the server being shut down.

It does not raise any exceptions. I tried with "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" setting of the VS 2010 without any success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope the following link would work for you. http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/04/logging-with-mongodb-and-c-prerequisites-first-run/

Comment: Thanks Rais. We are now using the latest version of C# driver.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue with MongoDb C# Driver.

From the documentation I found that they are resolving this issue in the version 1.1 of C# Driver.

The fix is available in the latest source code.

--Bharat